# How to change images in a selected div on mouse scroll like parallax effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all, thank you so much for checking my question.

I'm working on a web site and need to change images vertically in a selected div like a parallax effect. There are 3 images and need to change them.

There are 3 images in a div. Check the following screenshots.

This is the image 1. All these 3 images are half width of the screen.

[image]

And this is image 2.

[image]

Like this, there is another image 3. The yellow color content in the right side is not changing. Now i added just a simple scroll bar to scroll.

I need to add either parallax effect on these images to scroll vertically or quickly change images on mouse scroll.

Example for parallax effect I need to add : http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

Or I want to apply this effect : https://codepen.io/RenanB/pen/GZeBNg

```
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?image=1005" data-speed="-1" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed -1</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?image=1067" data-speed="1" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?gravity=center" data-speed="-0.25" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed -0.25</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?image=1080" data-speed="0.25" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed 0.25</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?random" data-speed="-0.75" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed -0.75</h2>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/1920/?blur" data-speed="0.75" class="img-parallax">
  <h2>Parallax Speed 0.75</h2>
</div>
```

But only issue is, when I apply the same code to my images, this effect is activating to my full site.

Most importantly ,no matter from where user scrolling the page, I need to scroll to these 3 images, show all 3 and then scroll down to next section.
I added above parallax code, but it's applying to the whole site and not working.

What is the best way to apply above mentioned 2 methods to my web site ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as soon as you played with code, you need to see that those scripts and effects builded inside a wrapper, so the main thing in parallax effect is to have a nicely 100% width and height so you can see the delay and responsiveness in your website, what I can tell you do is the following :

1. Wrap your images inside a div with name like ( image_wrapper ).
2. Add a class for every image parent div like ( image_section ).
3. specify the 100% width and height for image_sections.
4. Add a height for the image_wrapper as this :

   .image_wrapper{ height:calc( 100% * 4 ); }
   100% for the full height, 4 for the number of images to have in parallax